# Why the two CGRect don't intersect when they do visually?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, rect

I am building an app. It needs to accept user input from some `UITextField`s. And sometimes the keyboard will hide the text field so I need to move up the view when the keyboard `CGRect` intersects with the text field's `frame`.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/move-view-behind-keyboard-ios8-swift) an I added some of my own logic because I have multiple text fields.

Here is my relevant code: (The whole thing is in a VC that conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate`)

```
var focusedTextField: UITextField?
var viewMovedUp = false
var keyboardSize: CGRect!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("onRotate:"), name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil);
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    focusedTextField = textField
}

func onRotate (notification: NSNotification) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize =  (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            self.keyboardSize = keyboardSize
            assert(focusedTextField != nil)
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(focusedTextField!.bounds, keyboardSize){
                moveView(up: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if viewMovedUp {
        moveView(up: false)
    }
}

func moveView (up up: Bool) {
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
    let movement = (up ? -keyboardHeight : keyboardHeight)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
    })
    viewMovedUp = up
}
```

**If you don't want to read the whole code, I'll explain the gist of it.** So basically when the user taps on one of the text fields, `textFieldDidBeginEditing` gets called. That basically sets the `focusedTextField` to the text field that the user is editing. Then `keyBoardWillShow` gets called. It gets the keyboard size and assign it to a class-level variable called `keyboardSize` It then checks if the focused text field (remember that?) is covered by the keyboard (via `CGRectIntersectRect`). If it is then we move the view up by calling `moveView`. That method works perfectly fine so no need to explain.

Now on to the problem!

Let's look at a screen shot of the VC:

[image]

When I tap on the "Enter A" text field, the view moves up as expected. But when I tap on the "Enter P" text field, the keyboard shows up and covers the text field completely.

After some debugging, I found that

CGRectIntersectsRect(focusedTextField!.bounds, keyboardSize)

returns `false` so `moveView` is not called. The "Enter P" text field and keyboard size is as follows:

```
Bounds of text field:
    x: 62 y: 94.5
    height: 32.5 width: 278
Keyboard size:
    x: 0 y: 158
    height: 162 width: 568
```

Just from these figures, I don't think they overlap. But visually, they really do!

[image]

I also tried to change `focusedTextField!.bounds` to `focusedTextField.frame` but it still doesn't work.

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Comment: You'd probably have an easier time if you made your view controller a subclass of `UITableViewController`, and used a table view with static cells for layout. Then the table view controller would take care of the keyboard adjustment for you automatically.

Comment: @robmayoff I have a few questions concerning your suggestion. Actually my labels and text fields are dynamically generated. So I must use a prototype table view. Will that work? Also, if I used your suggestion, I would need to add the label and the text field to the table view cell programmatically. Am I right? If not, can you briefly explain how to do it using a prototype table view controller?

Comment: Yes, you can use a prototype-based table view. You can design your prototype cell in the storyboard with the label and the text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in this code:

```
CGRectIntersectsRect(focusedTextField!.bounds, keyboardSize)
```

...you are comparing apples and oranges:

- `focusedTextField!.bounds` is in the coordinate space of `focusedTextField`
- `keyboardSize` is in the coordinate space of *the window*

(And the reason why `focusedTextField.frame` didn't work is that it is in yet *another* coordinate space, that of the text field's superview.)

Those are two very different coordinate spaces, so you cannot compare these rects. You have to *convert* one of them to the coordinate space of the other.

For example, I think this will do it:

```
newKeyboardSize = focusedTextField.convertRect(keyboardSize, fromView:nil)
```

Now `newKeyboardSize` and `focusedTextField.bounds` should be in the same coordinate space.

Comment: And see the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_bounds_and_center