# How to hide keyboard in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am building an app that contains a `UITableViewController`. In the VC, I put some text fields for accepting user input. I use a table view controller because it's easier to move the view up when the keyboard appears. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822681/why-the-two-cgrect-dont-intersect-when-they-do-visually) for more info.

When I was learning how to hide the keyboard when the user taps somewhere else by watching one of thenewboston's videos, I was told to use

```
view.endEditing(true)
```

in the `touchesBegan` method.

I also found out how to use a swipe gesture recogniser so I could hide the keyboard when the user swipes down.

However, all of these are with normal view controllers. When I do this with a table view controller, nothing works! Both `touchesBegan` and `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` didn't work! When I swipe down or tap somewhere, the keyboard just stays there!

Why is this happening and how can I hide the keyboard in a table view controller?

EDIT:

The relevant code are all in a subclass of `UITableViewController`:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}


@IBAction func swipedDown(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) { // This is connected to a swipe gesture recogniser
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I think that's how you normally do it, right? I tried this in a normal view controller and it worked. It just doesn't work in table view controllers.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: @maddy edited. I think that's all the relevant code.

Comment: Are either of those two functions being called?

Comment: @maddy No, they are not called. This is really weird.

Comment: Not really. The table view is probably preventing the gestures from working.

Comment: @maddy Then how do I hide the keyboard? I see that the contacts app hides the keyboard when I swipe down. And it seems like a table view controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to override -touchesBegan:withEvent: for your UITableView, you will need to subclass UITableView.

touchesBegan:withEvent: is only sent to subclasses of UIView. You are  implementing touchesBegan:withEvent: in your controller.So, it won't work...

You can solve this with UIGestureRecognizer like this -

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
tap.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Then implement the handler -

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
// handling code
 self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Now call handleTap() at relevant position.

Comment: Where should I put the first code snippet? The view controller?

Comment: Yes in controller's  viewDidLoad, also check, I have edited some code , as you are using tableViewController replace tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tap) with self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

Answer (score 3):

You can add `tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.onDrag` on `viewDidLoad()` function of your `UITableViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.onDrag
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default UITableView handles all the gestures which cannot be overridden unless you add gestures on top of the tableView or handle `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` delegate.

By using `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` you can hide the keyboard. It'll be called only when the user scrolls. Touches and UIGestures won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a gesture recognizer to your tableView.

```
let dismissTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard:")
dismissTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
view.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTap)
```

and then in your dismissKeyboard selector:

```
func dismissKeyboard(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     view.endEditing(true)
}
```